PMD version: 7.3.0 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 67 with Java 23
I am trying to run PMD with a Java 23 project.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/reports/pmd</outputDirectory>
        <skipEmptyReport>false</skipEmptyReport>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

However, upon run, I am facing this issue:
[INFO] PMD version: 7.3.0
[ERROR] Parsing failed in ParseLock#doParse()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 67
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:200)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:180)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (ClassReader.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symbols.internal.asm.ClassStub$1.doParse (ClassStub.java:97)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symbols.internal.asm.ParseLock.getFinalStatus (ParseLock.java:33)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symbols.internal.asm.ParseLock.isFailed (ParseLock.java:66)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symbols.internal.asm.ClassStub.isUnresolved (ClassStub.java:511)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ClassTypeImpl.checkUserEnclosingTypeIsOk (ClassTypeImpl.java:452)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ClassTypeImpl.validateParams (ClassTypeImpl.java:418)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ClassTypeImpl.<init> (ClassTypeImpl.java:69)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ClassTypeImpl.<init> (ClassTypeImpl.java:64)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.TypeSystem.typeOf (TypeSystem.java:458)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.TypeSystem.rawType (TypeSystem.java:485)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.TypesFromReflection.fromReflect (TypesFromReflection.java:99)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.TypesFromReflection.fromReflect (TypesFromReflection.java:69)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ast.internal.PolyResolution.newStringCtx (PolyResolution.java:731)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ast.internal.PolyResolution.<init> (PolyResolution.java:98)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.types.ast.internal.LazyTypeResolver.<init> (LazyTypeResolver.java:116)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.InternalApiBridge.initTypeResolver (InternalApiBridge.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.internal.JavaAstProcessor.process (JavaAstProcessor.java:130)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.internal.JavaAstProcessor.process (JavaAstProcessor.java:164)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.internal.JavaAstProcessor.process (JavaAstProcessor.java:148)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParser.parseImpl (JavaParser.java:69)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParser.parseImpl (JavaParser.java:25)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.impl.javacc.JjtreeParserAdapter.parse (JjtreeParserAdapter.java:36)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.impl.PmdRunnable.parse (PmdRunnable.java:112)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.impl.PmdRunnable.processSource (PmdRunnable.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.impl.PmdRunnable.run (PmdRunnable.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:572)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1575)
[ERROR] Parsing failed in ParseLock#doParse()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 67

How to resolve this?

This question is related to but not a duplicate of the linked one since it doesn't show an UnsupportedClassError but instead an IllegalArgumentException because the default used PMD version of the maven plugin is not capable of analyzing the used Java bytecode version. In my opinion the question would deserve a tailored answer - an upgrade of the JVM or the compiler is not the solution here, you will have to specify the version of PMD to use in the maven plugin.

Just wanted to add: if it is a duplicate then one of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61417986/pmd-plugin-fails-with-java-14-unsupported-targetjdk (with a different JDK version but the answer guides you into the right direction).

I have replaced the duplicate with the one suggested by @cybertrain.
